# WP_User_Query breaks and ignore all codes below it

Tags: wordpress, mariadb

Previously, I used MariaDB 10.3 and my codes to display user with role "customer". Everything work fine

```
$count_args  = array(
    'role'      => 'customer',
    'fields'    => 'all_with_meta',
    'number'    => 999999      
);
$user_count_query = new WP_User_Query($count_args);
/*other codes to display the result from user_count_query variable*/
```

and result sample image
[sample image : working fine on old server](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JPuED.png)

And recently I changed to another hosting server that using MariaDb 10.5 and that page doesn't display any result. (same code as above)
[sample image: above code fail on new server](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HybFi.png)

However, when I made a small change In the new code by removing the "fields" argument as below

```
$count_args  = array(
    'role'      => 'customer',
//    'fields'    => 'all_with_meta',
    'number'    => 999999      
);
$user_count_query = new WP_User_Query($count_args);
/*other codes to display the result from user_count_query variable*/
```

and everything works again. [sample image: changes that works on new server](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JPuED.png)

I thought Mariadb 10.5 should have backward compatibility to MariaDb 10.3.

**UPDATE:** The following code will still work similar to original

```
 $count_args  = array(
    'role'      => 'customer',
    'fields'    => 'all',
    'number'    => 999999      
);
$user_count_query = new WP_User_Query($count_args);
/*other codes to display the result from user_count_query variable*/
```

The only changes here is using fields 'all' instead of 'all_with_meta'. However, on official document [wordpress WP_USER_QUERY](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wp_user_query/) 'all' and 'all_with_meta' are same.

**UPDATE Oct, 22,2021:** my current solution is to change "all_with_meta" to "all" for the attribute 'field' but would be nice if someone know why "all_with_meta" causes issue when upgrade from MariaDB 10.3 to MariaDB 10.5

**Can someone explain me what happened?**

**How do I use my original codes on the new server (without modification)?**

Thank you for reading

Comment: Can you check the error log on your new server?

Comment: I checked it but there wasn't any log regarding this issue. I turned on WP_DEBUG as well.